# Terminal hamburger menu

Tags: terminal, gnome

The ubuntu gnome terminal has additional buttons in its header.

[image: Terminal in ubuntu/gnome]

However the other linux distros, even the gnome-based, do not have such buttons.

[image: Terminal in arch/cinnamon]

Is there a way I can add the header buttons to the terminal in a non-ubuntu gnome-based linux distribution?

Comment: In `dconf-editor` navigate to `/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/headerbar` and enable this, then restart `gnome-terminal`. Does it help?

Comment: Yes, it did work! Thank you!